# What do you call it when you make a baby laugh?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What do you call it when you talk or make funny sounds to a baby to make it laugh or giggle?

Comment: I call it "making a baby laugh". If you want a specific word, how about "making-a-baby-laugh". I just coined it. How do you like it?

Comment: Can you give us a sentence where the word or phrase is a blank space or line so we have a better idea how you would use this word?

Comment: Can you record a video of yourself making these noises, so we know exactly what you're talking about? Or try to spell them out phonetically, that might be even more entertaining!

Answer (score 6):

***[Coochie, coochie coo!](http://www.scottishbooktrust.com/blog/2012/10/coochie-coochie-coo-the-natural-benefits-of-baby-talk)***  The natural benefits of baby talk

> - There are several names for this: ‘***baby talk’, 'motherese’ or ‘infant directed speech’.*** And although you might feel funny and friends and family might laugh as you converse with an infant, we do this without thinking and without explicit intention of speaking like this.
> - ***Men, women and children use infant directed speech (IDS) naturally when speaking to an infant or toddler***. Older children use IDS when speaking to younger children.

***[How to Make a Baby Laugh](http://m.wikihow.com/Make-a-Baby-Laugh):***

Try making funny noises or singing songs. Babies love unusual sounds. They will get your baby's attention.

> - Sing a song. Any song that has hand or body gestures will make your baby giggle. Try the "Itsy-Bitsy Spider" or even the "Hokey Pokey."
> - ***Play a funny sound.***  Kids like sounds that are odd or silly, such as farting noises. You may have to try different noises to see what your baby finds funny.
> - Kids also love animal sounds, so try copying the family cat or dog.
>     Try not to make these sounds too loud or startling. This might scare the baby!

Comment: Interesting fact:  babies' hearing isn't very well developed - they can only hear clearly at a narrow frequency range, which people **naturally** adjust their speaking tone into when they speak to babies - that high sing-song tone just happens to be perfect.  I don't know if that's evolution making us do that, or if we try lots of things and stick with the one that gets the reaction.  Isn't nature wonderful?

Answer (score 3):

[Baby Talk](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/parentese)

> The speech patterns and sounds of young children learning to talk, characterized by mispronunciation, imperfect syntax, repetition, and phonetic modifications, such as lisping or stuttering.
>
> The intentionally oversimplified manner of speech, imitative of young children learning to talk, used by adults in addressing children or pets.

[Motherese](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O29-MOTHERESE.html)

> A term used in the study of *Child Language Acquisition* for the way mothers talk to their young children. Its features include simplified grammar, exaggerated speech melody, diminutive forms of words such as doggie, and a highly repetitive style.

[Parentese](https://www.rhymeandreason.ca/blog/parentese-vs-baby-talk/)

> Parentese is that slower, higher-pitched, overly-exaggerated way of speaking to babies that you see most adults using. We open our eyes wider, put on big smiles, and over-enunciate the words we're saying.

[Infant Directed Speech](https://naomitawil.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/chapter-5-infant-directed-speech/)

> During infant interaction, a specific kind of language is used, often referred to as *motherese*. Also known as Infant Directed Speech, *motherese* is language spoken in an exaggerated rhythm or melody, therefore emphasizing word and phrase boundaries.

[Child Directed Speech](http://www.earlyliteracylearning.org/cellpract_pract/infant/PGPrac_I_ChildDirSpch_WM.pdf)

> Adults in most parts of the world speak to infants differently than they do others. When talking to babies they use high-pitched and elongated words in an exaggerated manner with lots of facial expressiveness.

[Lallation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lallation)

> Baby-talk or gibberish

Answer (score 2):

I would call it **coochie-cooing**, from the phrase often used when tickling a baby (you can [see Fred Flintstone learn to do it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3xqhPfieEc)). This is a specific form of baby-talk or ***motherese***:

> noun
>   1. the simplified and repetitive type of speech, with exaggerated intonation and rhythm, often used by adults when speaking to babies.
>   [—Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/motherese)

Be aware, however, that in a different context the phrase (and the single word coochie/coochy/coochee) [means something entirely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coochee).